# MVC Conditional CSS formatting - Max value

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to use conditional CSS formatting to highlight a row in a table based on a value?

In my scenario I have a MVC Page (Razor) with a ViewModel containing an ICollection and I would like to use CSS to highlight the row with the highest particular property (Score) value.  Can this be done?

Thanks,

Comment: What does "based on a value" mean exactly - is it about specific values that you can string match, or "> 50" kind of stuff? Can you use JavaScript? (It's likely to be impossible with pure CSS)

Comment: If css can, probably IE can't.

Answer (score 1):

You should figure out which rows is highest in your controller, add a variable to your ViewModel indicating which row is the "highest" and flag that TR element with a class when you build the table.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways of doing this.

1. Use Javascript to detect the row with the highest value and add a CSS class.
2. In your controller, when you load the collection, mark the object that contains the maximum value somehow, then check for this max in your Razor view to conditionally change the CSS class of the row.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply setup your Razor code to add a class to the row when a particular condition is met?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, was shying away from Javascript as thats not my strong point, so will try using the controller.  Unfortunately, the values could be of any value so cannot use a particular condition.

Answer (score 0):

Not absolutely sure but I doubt you can do that with CSS alone. Definitely doable with Javascript.